# Storing multiple values in XML

Tags: xml

Is it possible to store multiple values , for example values in an array into a single XML element?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.  You can store, for example, a comma-separated list of values in a single element.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [serializer attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

e.g. :

```
[XmlAttribute]
```

this will put the element on the same line as the parent-node.

an object as seen below

```
[Serializable]
public class TopNode
{
    public TopNode(){}
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Level{ get; set; }
}
```

would give an xml output similar to:

```
<TopNode Name="xxx" Level"1"/>
```

However, if you are only interested in having all elements on one row in 1 single xml element literally, then adding a property to your class that adds all data in a single string can also be done of course.

```
public string OneOneLine
{
    get
    {
        string s;
        s = String.Concat( ..... )
    }
}
```

this will then be put on a single line with all your information the way you choose.